# import file_a to file_b and file_b to file_a

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

My file structure is:

```
Project/
--classes.py
--display.py
--logic.py
--main.py
--settings.py
```

main.py imports

```
from display import display_student_list
from logic import register, welcome, stud_search
```

display.py imports

```
from logic import display_json 
from settings import WORKDIR
```

settings.py imports

```
import os
```

and then

logic.py imports

```
from display import display_search
from classes import student
from settings import WORKDIR
```

The problem I'm having is when I import `from display import display_search` in logic.py it throws me an `ImportError cannot import 'display_search'`,

but when I remove it, all works fine. It works also when I import it from another place like main.py

Is it wrong to import from *file_a to file_b* **and** *file_b to file_a*
I tried changing both to "from display import *", "from logic import *" and it works, why does importing a function name won't work?

Comment: Are you sure `display.py` has a function called `display_search`?

Comment: You can't have circular imports, since it will recurse infinitely.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I even tried importing display_search from another file, it works on main.py but also won't work on settings.py

Comment: @Barmar oh yeah, that makes sense. Thank you! I didn't realized it lol, but why does "from file import *" works but not "from file import function" i'm now just curious.